# Cleaning sentences through Tf-idf values and retaining only high tf-idf score words in the sentence in Python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, out-of-memory, tf-idf

I have a dataset in the form that I have a sentence and for each sentence, I have the tf-idf value for each relevant word in that sentence.

```
Sample dataset:
                                            heel syrup word3 word4 word5
    So what is a better exercise            0     0     0      0    0.34 
    how many days hv to take syrup          0   0.95    0      0     0      
    Can I take this solution ?              0   0   0   0      0.23
```

The dataset is really huge and has around 10K rows which are sentences and 5K columns which are words.
From here I want to make a new column and for each sentence, keep words that have tf-idf value greater than 0.6.
The code implemented is:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'Desktop/tfidf_val.csv')

dataset.apply(lambda x: x.index[x.astype(bool)].tolist(), 1)
```

but I am getting a Memory Error. Any idea how to solve this or if there's an issue with the code

Answer (score 1):

I once had this issue and my solution was to replace:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'filename.csv')
```

with

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'filename.csv',sep=';',low_memory=False)
```

EDIT:
Since you column contains commas and the file is comma separated, you need to know how many columns you have. When you do, saty it is M, add this :

```
n = M
df = pd.read_csv(r'filename.csv', 
                 usecols=range(M),
                 lineterminator='\n',       header=None,low_memory=False))
```

Comment: I am getting this error "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 128, saw 3"

Comment: That means you have commas in the first column. Is your original Df separated by, or ;?

Comment: It's comma separated

Comment: What does n = M do? Tried it but getting this error "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory"

Comment: M is the number of column in your dataframe. Sp, if you know there are 10 columns, them M = 10.